# not getting dropdown list in _layout file in asp.net mvc project

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

i am trying to get a drop down list in navbar using my `_layout.cshtml` file of asp.net mvc project but for some reason the drop down list is not working. heres the code -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - JwtAuthorisationProj</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />

    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.css"
          rel="stylesheet" type='text/css'>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">

    <style>

        /* Navbar container */
        .navbar {
            overflow: hidden;
            background-color: #f9f7f5;
            font-family: Arial;
        }

            /* Links inside the navbar */
            .navbar a {
                float: left;
                font-size: 16px;
                color: black;
                text-align: center;
                padding: 14px 16px;
                text-decoration: none;
            }

        /* The dropdown container */
        .dropdown {
            float: left;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

            /* Dropdown button */
            .dropdown .dropbtn {
                font-size: 16px;
                border: none;
                outline: none;
                color: black;
                padding: 14px 16px;
                background-color: inherit;
                font-family: inherit; /* Important for vertical align on mobile phones */
                margin: 0; /* Important for vertical align on mobile phones */
            }



        /* Dropdown content (hidden by default) */
        .dropdown-content {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            background-color: palegreen;
            min-width: 160px;
            box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
            z-index: 1;
        }

            /* Links inside the dropdown */
            .dropdown-content a {
                float: none;
                color: black;
                padding: 12px 16px;
                text-decoration: none;
                display: block;
                text-align: left;
            }

                /* Add a grey background color to dropdown links on hover */
                .dropdown-content a:hover {
                    background-color: #ddd;
                }

        /* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
        .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
            display: block;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">JwtAuthorisationProj</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex justify-content-between">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
                        </li>



                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <div class="dropdown">
                                <button class="dropbtn">
                                    Click &emsp;
                                    <i style="height: 18px; width: 18px;" class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                                </button>
                                <div class="dropdown-content">
                                    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                                    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                                    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>



                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>

    <footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
        <div class="container">
            &copy; 2021 - JwtAuthorisationProj - <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

on hover i should get div with link1, link2, link3. but its not working here but when i copy this code in normal html file and then open it i am getting the drop down properly.  can anyone help?

Comment: Why aren't you leveraging bootstraps dropdown controls, if you have already available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> on hover i should get div with link1, link2, link3. but its not working here but when i copy this code in normal html file and then open it i am getting the drop down properly. can anyone help?

That is because you use bootstrap.css in your _Layout.cshtml, and it contains some same class name with what you defined here. They conflict with each other.

You need remove `overflow: hidden;` in both `.navbar` and `.dropdown` class like below to make your css work:

```
.navbar {
    /*overflow: hidden;*/
    background-color: #f9f7f5;
    font-family: Arial;
}
.dropdown {
    float: left;
    /*overflow: hidden;*/
}
```

Result:

[image]

Or you can use the default bootstrap css instead of custom css, you can follow the reference below:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/69400191/11398810